# ¿Porque me sale este error al querer EJECUTAR MI SCRIPT EN PYTHON?

Tags: python, vscode, script, web-scrapping

¿Por qué me sale este error al ejecutar Script en `PYTHON`?

> PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Otros\Pruebas de Python> & "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Otros/Pruebas de Python/de/Scripts/Activate.ps1"
> & : **No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Otros\Pruebas de Python\de\Scripts\Activate.ps1 porque la ejecución de
> scripts está deshabilitada en este sistema. Para obtener más información, consulta el tema about_Execution_Policies en
> https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. & "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Otros/Pruebas de Python/de/Scripts/Activate ...**
> + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
> PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Otros\Pruebas de Python> & "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Otros/Pruebas de Python/de/Scripts/python.exe" "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Otros/Pruebas de Python/WebScrping.py"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Otros\Pruebas de Python\WebScrping.py", line 1, in 
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Comment: El comando que ejecuta el script está tratando de activar un entorno virtual de Python a través de PowerShell. PS viene desactivado por defecto. Puedes intentar [habilitarlo](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+activate.ps1) o usar el archivo **activate.bat** que se encuentra en la misma ruta. Una vez resuelvas lo anterior y te sigue saliendo error de bs4, entonces instalar `pip install beautifulsoup4` en el entorno virtual.